# Fire function if input value is < 0.2 in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to fire `.focusout()` only if `myInput.val() < 0.2` now it fires unconditionally. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

```js
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('input', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
    if (parseFloat(myInput.val()) < 0.2  ) {
        jQuery('.alert').hide();
        jQuery(this).focusout(function() {
            jQuery(this).val('0,2');
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<span class="alert">alert</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not conditionally *executing* the `focusout` event, you're conditionally *creating* it.  Once it's created, it will always execute.

Create the event as normal, but put the condition in the event itself.  The event will *always* execute, but the logic therein will change based on the condition.  Something like this:

```
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('input', function () {
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
    if (parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) < 0.2  ) {
        jQuery('.alert').hide();
    }
});

jQuery('input[type=text]').focusout(function() {
    if (parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) < 0.2  ) {
        jQuery(this).val('0,2');
    }
});
```

Note: I'm *mostly* guessing as to the intended functionality here.  But the idea itself is simple enough.  Keep the events separate, assume the events will *always* fire, and conditionally respond to those events as per your logic.  Don't try to conditionally fire the events themselves.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `myInput.val()) < 0.2` is fulfilled at least once. The the `focusout` event stays in the memory and there you're setting the value unconditionally. Following code will fix your code:

```js
jQuery('input[type=text]').on('input', function () {
    var myInput = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/,/g, '.'));
    if (parseFloat(myInput.val()) < 0.2  ) {
        jQuery('.alert').hide();
        jQuery(this).focusout(function() {
            parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) < 0.2 && jQuery(this).val('0.2');
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<span class="alert">alert</span>
```

Comment: This will also attach a new `focusout` handler every time the input changes.  Better to attach the handler outside of other handlers.